# Calling WCF service from another WCF service (routing)

Tags: c#, wcf, web, networking, routes

i have WCF service (RootService) hosted on IIS on server. For example on port 5000. I need to call another service (AdvancedService), hosted on the same IIS on different port. For example on port 6000. There shouldn't be any problem with calling that.

I would like to ask for routing.

I will call RootService from any client. The request will do through internet. E.G. https://217.48.48.48:5000/RootService.svc. And then my RootService call AdvancedService by https://217.48.48.48:6000/AdvancedService.svc. 
Will be request routed through the internet, or just only through local network, server or just only IIS?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: It really depends on your network configuration. If you want to be sure your request isn't routed through internet, use `127.0.0.1` instead

Comment: In my opinion, route service is just like a wcf client (relative to the final service your client wants to call), it receives message from client and resends the message to the final service, if you could call your service as a normal wcf client, your route service should also be able to call the service, it just relies on the client  endpoint configuration of your route service.